# DataBind variable to ListBox.SelectedItem property

Tags: c#, data-binding, silverlight-4.0, listbox

I have a ListBox (lstBxsources) that is populated correctly and works like it should.

```
<ListBox Name="lstBxSources" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Path=Description}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

I also have a UserControl(MyUserControl).

```
<MainControl:MyControl x:Name="MyUserControl" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

MyUserControl has Dependency Property on it called 'CurrentSourceProperty'

```
    public SourceInfo CurrentSource
    {
        get { return (SourceInfo)GetValue(CurrentSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CurrentSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentSource", typeof(SourceInfo), typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

I have databound the CurrentSource to the SelectedItem of the lstBxSources like so:

```
 MyUserControl.SetBinding(MyControl.CurrentSourceProperty, new Binding() { Source = lstBxSources.SelectedItem});
```

This works initially but will not update when the SelctedItem is changed.

Any idea why it won't update for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it... fix your binding like this:

```
MyUserControl.SetBinding(MyControl.CurrentSourceProperty,
new Binding() { 
  Source = lstBxSources, 
  Path= new PropertyPath("SelectedItem")
  });
```

---

If I got you right, put this code inside MyUserControl:

```
MyAnotherControl.SetBinding(AnotherControl.currentSourceInfoProperty,
    new Binding()
    {
        Source = this,
        Path = new PropertyPath("CurrentSource"),
            Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
    });
```

Comment: So simple.. it seems I always do that. Thank you!

Comment: Lets say I have another user control in MyUserControl that has another variable that I want to bind to CurrentSource. How would I do that? I have the following:
    anotherControl.SetBinding(anotherControl.currentSourceInfoProperty, new Binding() { Source = CurrentMapSource, Path = new PropertyPath("SourceInfo") });


But it doesn't update after the first time either.

Comment: You're very wellcom... again :o)